# canvas color gradient animation error :Failed to execute 'createRadialGradient': The provided double value is non-finite

Tags: canvas

I am trying to review what I have learned and intend to make just a single circle color gradient animation, this error still comes up as always which is kinda confused me. The scripts are as following:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
console.log(canvas.width,canvas.height);


ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
function drawCircle(x,y,r){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.height,canvas.width);
    requestAnimationFrame(drawCircle);

    var grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(x,y,0,x,y,r);
    var colorArray = ['blue','yellow','green','red','grey'];
    grad.addColorStop(0,colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArray.length)]);
    grad.addColorStop(.3,colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArray.length)]);
    grad.addColorStop(.5,colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArray.length)]);
    grad.addColorStop(.6,colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArray.length)]);
    grad.addColorStop(.9,colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArray.length)]);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = grad;
    ctx.fill();
}

drawCircle(100,100,20);
```

would anyone please check this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring because, you are not passing the parameters *(x, y, r)* when calling the `drawCircle` function through *requestAnimationFrame*.

So, to resolve the issue, you need to call the function, like so ...

```
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    drawCircle(x, y, r);
});
```

---

```js
canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;

function drawCircle(x, y, r) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
    
    var grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0, x, y, r);
    var colorArray = ['blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'red', 'grey'];
    grad.addColorStop(0, colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)]);
    grad.addColorStop(0.3, colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)]);
    grad.addColorStop(0.5, colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)]);
    grad.addColorStop(0.6, colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)]);
    grad.addColorStop(0.9, colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)]);
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = grad;
    ctx.fill();
 
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        drawCircle(x, y, r);
    });
}

drawCircle(100, 100, 20);
```

```css
body{overflow:hidden}canvas {border: 1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Sorry, I just went back from the college, yes I am kinda missed to passing those parameters when callback the function, thanks for your help!